# Extraneous spacing between paragraph and table in HTML Email

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email

I have a paragraph tag followed by a table.

```
<p style="font:100 15px/23px Arial;margin:8px 0;padding:0;color:#4d4e53;">TEXT</p>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;color:#4d4e53;margin:0;padding:0;">
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align:top;padding:8px 0;font:700 15px/23px">TEXT</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This looks exactly as I expect in dozens of scenarios (16px of space between, 8 from paragraph's margin and 8 from table cell's padding) except for Outlook versions 2007, 2010, and 2013.

And it's a VERY large difference. Here's the spacing between the paragraph and the table in Outlook:

[image]

Not certain if this will help, but when highlighted with the cursor it looks like this, suggesting that it's a spacing issue on the paragraph. I have several stacked paragraphs, and they don't have this problem.

[image]

Anyone seen this or have any suggestions?

**Tried**

And this is by no means a complete list...

Adding mso specific styling to the table:

```
mso-margin-top-alt:0px; mso-margin-bottom-alt:0px; mso-padding-alt: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
```

Splitting all the `padding:0;` out into `padding-top:0;padding-right:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:0;`

Removing the whitespace (a line break) between the p and table tags.

**Round 2**

Replacing all the p tags with div

The "Margin" (capitalize M) trick, then with all 4 margins broken out separately.

Also mso specific css:

```
mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;
```

Comment: Can you include the complete code of your email?

Comment: @GeoffPhillips alas, I cannot. I did figure it out however, see answer :)

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that Outlook doesn't play nicely with block elements sitting next to non-block elements (that's my guess, anyhow).

The solution was to wrap my preceeding paragraphs in a div, like so:

```
<div>
  <p style="font:100 15px/23px Arial;margin:8px 0;padding:0;color:#4d4e53;">TEXT</p>
</div>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;color:#4d4e53;margin:0;padding:0;">
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align:top;padding:8px 0;font:700 15px/23px">TEXT</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```